# Missing menu in Xcode when trying to setup splashscreen

Tags: xcode

Can anyone please tell me how I can access this menu in Xcode?

[image]

This is my current view:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an old version of xcode, hard to remember.

Comment: How can I add a splash image using 11.4?

Comment: This is not the same question! You must open a new one...but add an ImageView, fill your assets with some images, and then use the settings of the image view to let it use an image...

Comment: The only tutorials I can find use the menu in my initial question - which I can't find in the current Xcode layout